# Having iOS and macOS app in same Xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, app-store

I want to make a Mac version of my iOS app. I have never done this before and have three questions I could not find answers to on the internet.

**1)** Should I add a new target for the Mac component in my iOS app's Xcode project? If so, is there a way to only send new updates for the iOS version to the App Store if the Mac app is not ready yet?

**2)** I will like to use iCloud syncing for both apps so changes the user makes on the iOS app can go to the Mac one (vice versa). Does the Mac and iOS app both need to be in the same Xcode project for this to happen?

**3)** When I want to add an app to App Store Connect, I only get the option of "New App" (iOS or tvOS apps) or "New macOS App". If they're in the same Xcode Project how can I send both (iOS and Mac app) to the App Store?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ad 1.) You should if you of want to share certain parts of code. It also makes it easier to maintain across releases with git.

ad 2.) No. But the shared icloud container will only work after one app has been already approved by apple.

ad 3.) No, OSX apps and ios/tvos apps do not share the same appstore entry, independently of them being in the same xcode project or not.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. I just want to clarify the app store process question. To send an app to the App Store, I go to Product -> Archive then "Distribute App" from the archive page. I made a fake Xcode project (started as a macOS app then added an iOS target). When I archived this project, there is only one archive of type "macOS App Archive" and there's no archive of type "iOS App Archive" for the iOS component. **How can I separate to two targets (Mac app and iOS app) so that I can only send the iOS version to the App Store, especially if there is no iOS archive?**

Comment: If you run archive, it always will archive the currently selected target with its build scheme. They then get grouped by platform in the organizer screen, from where you can distribute them. So if you archive YourApp-iOS it wont create an archive for OSX at all.